# Simulate a button click on a grouplist in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have the following HTML:

```
►<li class="addToGroupList item sc-border-light-top">~</li>
►<li class="addToGroupList item sc-border-light-top">~</li>
► li class addToGroupList item sc-border-light-top >_ /li == $0
▼<li class="addToGroupList item sc-border-light-top">
▼ <div class="groupItem sc-media">
▼ <div class="sc-media">
▼<a href="/groups/electronic-dance-music-l" class="groupItem coverArt sc-media-image" title="Go" to electronic dance music - you sexy beat.>
<span style="background-image:url(https://il.sndcdn.com/artworks-000000484010-ephjo0-t120x120.jpg);width:48px;height:48px;" class="sc-artwork sc-artwork-
placeholder-10 " aria-label="Electronic Dance Music - You sexy beat.” aria-role="img"></span>
</a>
▼<h3 class="groupItem title sc-media-content">
<a href="/groups/electronic-dance-music-l" class="groupItem title-link sc-link-dark sc-truncate” title="Go" to electronic dance music - you sexy beat.>
Electronic Dance Music - You sexy beat.
</a>
</h3>
▼ <div class="groupItem actions sc-button-toolbar">
::before
<button class="addToGroupButton sc-button-blue sc-button sc-button-medium sc-button-responsive sc-button-selected" tabindex="0" title="Remove">Added</button>
::after
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
►<li class="addToGroupList item sc-border-light-top">~</li>
►<li class="addToGroupList item sc-border-light-top">-</li>
```

I would like to create a loop on the groupList in order to click then unclick all the buttons inside the groupList but when i try:
`document.getElementById('/groups/electronic-dance-music-1').click();`
i get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null(…)
Is it the right way to go?

Comment: There is no element with an id of `/groups/electronic-dance-music-1`

Comment: Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent

Answer (score 0):

Don't call an event handler directly, just dispatch an event and let the browser do anything else.

```
document.getElementById('elementID').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

Your id is strange. Give tags you want to refer by id an `id` attribute.

```
<tagname id="my-element-id">
```

Comment: Note that since the Event constructor defaults the `bubbles` and `cancelable` properties to `false` any event handler that catches the event that isn't constructed to have those set to true will not be able to prevent event bubbling or prevent the default action respectively

Comment: Good remark @PatrickEvans! When needed use `new Event('click', { /* settings go here */ })`. Further is to be said that some default action is to be triggered by the developer itself, e.g. when simulating a link click, you can trigger handlers via `dispatchEvent` but have also to call `element.click` to make the `href` attribute take effect. In that case you might be interested if `preventDefault` has been called by some handler.